# Wordpress and database basics. Where to start?

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Hope you are doing all ok.

I am new to programming and I've been messing around with some things: javascript in Google app script, some python lines too, and some basic SQL skills too. I managed to create a simple system for a nonprofit organization and now I would like to learn about Wordpress and how to connect a database (phpmyadmin from xampp) to my Wordpress Frankenstein. I managed to create a simple (VERY simple) site and I've been playing a while with xampp, but now i would like to:

1- send data to my database from my Wordpress site (I know how to build a form already).

2- send data from my database to my Wordpress site.

3- edit data stored in my database using a Wordpress form.

I know there are a LOT of things involved in my questions but I just want a... mmmmmm... starting point, maybe? what should I learn, read, study to accomplish this task?

Sorry if this question is too newbie or basic for some people here but as I said before: I am learning. I've been looking around for about one month but I really don't understand how it works.

Thanks a lot guys/girls for taking the time to read my question and, more important, thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is considered off-topic over here. However, I can understand that I'm-a-bit-lost feeling you have right now as we all have been there, too. My advice: don't focus on WordPress. Learn PHP instead (which WordPress uses). As ProgramGeek01 said below, there are many resources online you can use to improve your skills as a developer. Just pick one and start from there.

Comment: Oh!!! sorry bro, thanks a lot for your advice, i really appreciate that you understand i feel kind of lost here. Have a great night bud.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to start learning a language/how to achieve something is to either take a course on coursera/khan academy/youtube or google it!
A few quick resources I found:

1) [Working with Databases in Wordpress](https://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-databases-in-wordpress/)

2)[How to build a Wordpress Database Table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IwNiCgM6lU)

3)[Beginners Wordpress Database Guide](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/database/)

Hope it was helpful!

PS:First Answer, if anything is wrong with this please let me know!

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. It is very helpful to have some advice related to "how to start to". have a great night bud.

Answer (score 0):

The situation each and every of us faced when we have been started ! 
Lets share my learning from that mistake with you.

1. Don't focus on too many thing.
2. First use WordPress and all popular plugins as user and try to understand how its work and what is the usability of the plugin.
3. try to read some guideline , Obviously w3 school.
4. If you are not good in PHP , Then try to learn PHP first. Then OOP in PHP from w3 school.
5. After that try to start developing a small plugin like "A plugin to print Sunshine after each content " or "A Plugin to extend Wp User Profile Info Like to add Facebook link or Twitter Link"
6. Both having proper tutorial. So check carefully from envato tutus.
7. Start learning by building things , Not like start learning by only reading. And thats the journey --- let me know if there I can help you in any way :)

Comment: oooook, now i see the number 1 is extremely important. I've been taking program courses at the university, excel courses, reading about python, java, javascript, wordpress, SQL. It has been kind of difficult, but your advice is really important. I will take it into account for my research. Have a great night bro.